# sublimeLinter "Error trying to parse file: Expected value in Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap:2:1"

Tags: sublimelinter

Error: "Error trying to parse file: Expected value in Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap:2:1"

Hello, I have googled this and only found old documentation posts and answers for this problem that was on ST2 but not 3 and was posted in 2013.

I also have tried visiting the troubling shooting in the official site for sublimeLinter and the error does not seem to be listed. I guess I am one of the few who are running into this.

I am fairly new to using a text editor like ST3, so some of the terminology I am not too familiar with.

Is it possible anyone may help me with this?

So far I have attempted:

Preference>Package Control> User Settings/ Which is empty and attempted typing in some of the old answer problems.

I also attempted in pasting in:

```
[
 { "keys": ["ctrl+t","u"], "command": "upper_case" },
 { "keys": ["ctrl+t","l"], "command": "lower_case" }
]
```

that was from an answer in a older post that I found. However, the problem still persist and I ran into a brick wall when attempting to find more answers. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I have similar problem in windows with my keymap files.  Even trying to  re-save and existing keymap file, with no changes fails to save, giving a similar error message.  Everytime I open Sublime Text 3, I get a couple of these Error windows that popup.  For example `Error trying to parse file: Expected value in Packages\SublimeLinter\keymaps\Default(Windows).sublime-keymap:1:1`

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question but I came across the same error message having tried to use the sublime linter package(s) and then deciding to uninstall. After I did this I got a similar error message to the one you describe.

I opened Preferences->Key Bindings and found the following line in the Default (OSX).sublime-keymap-User file:

```
/User/Default ().sublime-keymap
```

I commented this line out so that I now have an empty file and the error on startup has disappeared.

Comment: it works for linux as well by commenting out the /User/Default ().sublime-keymap

Comment: It still does not work for me on Mac

Answer (score 0):

Simply put it inside double qoutes! it solve my problem
simple do ->

```
"/User/Default ().sublime-keymap"
```

And save your setting, then close sublime and repopen. You'll not see this pop again